# Spring: Configure security for actuator endpoints with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

Is it possible to configure security for actuator endpoints of a Spring application with Spring Security in a generic way?

According to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8646 I need to do this in my custom Spring Security configuration.

But suppose I have both a custom request mapping for `/info` in my application (on port 8080) and also the actuator info endpoint enabled on port 8081. How can I distinguish these two in Spring Security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible but not particularly obvious. In your extension of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` you can inject a collection of the actuator endpoints:

```
@Inject
private List<AbstractEndpointMvcAdapter<? extends Endpoint<?>>> actuatorEndpoints;
```

Then in your override of `configureHttpSecurity(HttpSecurity http)` you can use the `getPath()` member of each actuator endpoint to pass to the `.requestMatchers(forPortAndPath(managementPort, actuatorPath))` builder available on the `http` argument.

Comment: Thank you! Actually in my case I just wanted to ignore management endpoints from spring security, so having `@Value("${management.port:8081}")` and `.requestMatchers(request -> request.getServerPort() == managementPort)` did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that Spring Boot 2 explicitly addresses this problem.
See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints-security

Comment: @adrhc Not sure what you mean. The above link works for me. This is the link for the current release: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints-security